# immutable? function not defined in Racket

Tags: racket

I was reading the racket documentation about strings and came across the immutable? function. I tried to use it on racket but it didn't work. It says it's not defined.
I'm using beginner student whit 2htdp/image.rkt and universe.rkt.

```lisp
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.8 [cs].
Language: Beginning Student [custom]; memory limit: 128 MB.
Teachpacks: 2htdp/image.rkt and universe.rkt.
> (immutable? "test")
immutable?: this function is not defined
>
```

Comment: Beginner student language only contains a very small subset of the full Racket language. You should treat it as an entirely different language. A lot of the things you see on the full Rackets docs will not be available in BSL. Make sure you reference the [BSL documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html)

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=%20immutable%3F%20) you'll see `immutable?` is  provided from `racket/base` or `racket`. I.e. You need to use `#lang racket` or `#lang racket/base`. DrRacket has many other languages where you might require it, however there is no guarantee that it will work since some features are in direct conflict. Eg. I'm pretty sure `#!r6rs` probably won't work.